# JQuery - select-result show message on select

Tags: javascript, jquery, show, selectable

plugin demo: http://jqueryui.com/selectable/#serialize

Hello, I don't quite understand this "plugin" and specifically

`result.append( " #" + ( index + 1) );`  &

`<span>You've selected:</span> <span id="select-result">none</span>.`

I want the user to be able to select one of the following "buttons" and then a message to show in place of the Number selected (as in the demo)

So: You've selected: #2.
Would be:  You've selected: UK, please goto this and do that etc...

im guessing the easiest way is with JavaScript

```
if "select-result" = 1 then
else
```

Sort of thing?

Any help Would be great! i hope this isn't a stupid question...

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery UI Selectable - Serialize</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery- ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<style>
#feedback { font-size: 1.4em; }
#selectable .ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
#selectable .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }
#selectable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
#selectable li { margin: 3px; padding: 0.4em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }
</style>
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#selectable" ).selectable({
  stop: function() {
    var result = $( "#select-result" ).empty();
    $( ".ui-selected", this ).each(function() {
      var index = $( "#selectable li" ).index( this );
      result.append( " #" + ( index + 1) );
    });
  }
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="feedback">
<span>You've selected:</span> <span id="select-result">none</span>.
</p>

<ol id="selectable">
<li class="ui-widget-content">UK</li>
<li class="ui-widget-content">USA</li>
<li class="ui-widget-content">FR</li>
<li class="ui-widget-content">AU</li>
<li class="ui-widget-content">CA</li>
<li class="ui-widget-content">DE</li>
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var index = $( "#selectable li" ).index( this );
```

This grabs the index of the element we've been passed. We don't need this line.

```
result.append( " #" + ( index + 1) );
```

The index is the position at which the element occurs while descending the DOM.

We can change the above lines to one simple thing.

```
$( ".ui-selected", this ).text().appendTo(result);
```

*Edit*: See above, `this` may refer to the entire ul, so we need to filter it by the item that is selected. If you are allowing for a multi-select, then see below.

```
$( ".ui-selected", this ).each(function(){
    $(this).text().appendTo(result);
});
```

Comment: It seems to think it's selected everything? and displays list with bullet points? am i doing something wrong?

Comment: @user1871802 Give it a go now. Small oversight perhaps.

Comment: Hey Thanks For you on going help :) its must be me i get this result: http://i.imgur.com/TGq36sL.png  just a dot?

Answer (score 0):

the example in the plugins is showing the selected index.. you don't need to do that... what you need to do is get the text of selected and show it in span.. so use.. `html()` or `text()`..

try this

```
 $(function() {
   $( "#selectable" ).selectable({
    stop: function() {
         var result = $( "#select-result" );
         result.html($(this).html());  // result.text($(this).text());
    }
  });
});
```